# Chromecast detect mute/unmute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromecast

I am currently working with the [Chromecast API for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/).

Its possible to detect if the user has changed the mute/unmute state with the chromecast extension?

If I click the mute / unmute button neither the `sessionUpdateListener` nor `mediaStatusUpdateListener` will be fired. Play / pause fires the events as expected.

Is there another event i can listen to?

Comment: Confirmed that neither sessionUpdateListener nor mediaStatusUpdateListener gets fired when mute/unmute is clicked from the Cast extension.  If you mute/unmute from within app (e.g. setting receiver volume call), you get a session update listener.  Filed a bug to get this addressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its possible to track this bug?

Comment: This issue has been addressed in the new version of Cast extension (14.916.0.6).

Comment: So it should be fixed or? :) i will test it today.

Comment: I verified that the new Cast extension fires sessionUpdateListener now, if you add  it like this: session.addUpdateListener(sessionUpdateListener.bind(this)); It won't fire mediaStatusUpdateListener though.  It's by design.

Comment: I also verify that its fired now. But the Volume object always says: `{ level: 1, muted: false }`, even if its muted. Could somebody check that?